# C dynamic memory / C string

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is something similar to what I am trying to do (I skipped code which checks if memory was allocated):

```
    sscanf(line, "%[^\"]\"%[^\"]", tempString, tempString);
    int length = strlen("stackoverflow.com") + strlen(tempString);
    tempQuestion.link = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    tempQuestion.link = "stackoverflow.com";
    strcat(tempQuestion.link, tempString);
```

Program crashes after it reaches strcat. I can't figure out what could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign `tempQuestion.link = "stackoverflow.com"`
you change the pointer `tempQuestion.link`.  You want to use strncpy to copy the string.

Change the last two lines to

```
strncpy(tempQuestion.link, "stackoverflow.com", length);
strcat(tempQuestion.link, tempString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line causes the error,

```
tempQuestion.link = "stackoverflow.com";
```

Instead copy as follows,

```
strcpy(tempQuestion.link, "stackoverflow.com");
```